# Replicating a Specific Table of Contents (Report Class)

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am writing a long publication usign the `report` class. I am trying to replicate the following table of contents

[image]

I have search the web but have had difficulty replicating the above table of contents. A MWE of my current table of contents is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Example 1}
Example 1
\section{Section example}
Section example
\subsection{Subsection example}
Subsection example
\end{document}
```

**Update**

In response to the brilliant post by leandriis, how can I remove "Chapter 3" and "Chapter 4" next to "Discussion" and "Future work" respectively in the table of contents below?
[image]

The code that I used is given below.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\normalfont,
                      pagenumberformat=\normalfont,
                      entrynumberformat={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~}},
                      linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill, 
                      numsep=1em,
                      beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
                      dynnumwidth]
                     {tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
Example 1
\chapter{Example 2}
Example 2
\section{Section example}
Section example
\subsection{Subsection example}
Subsection example
\chapter{Discussion}
\chapter{Future work}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `tocloft` package?

```
% reptocprob.tex  SE 599046

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{comment}

%\begin{comment}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % dots after chapter entries
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{8em} % increase space for chapter numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % put this before chapter numbers

%\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
Example 1
\chapter{Example 2}
Example 2
\section{Section example}
Section example
\subsection{Subsection example}
Subsection example

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\thechapter{}}}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\chapter{Discussion}  % prints Chapter and Discussion and adds to the ToC
\chapter*{Future work} % prints Future work
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Future work} % adds Future work to the ToC

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wasn't sure how you coded the "Discussion" and "Future work" chapters in your document so I gave two methods for dealing with these in the document and the ToC.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the `tocbasic` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\normalfont,
                      pagenumberformat=\normalfont,
                      entrynumberformat={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~}},
                      linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill, 
                      numsep=1em,
                      beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
                      dynnumwidth]
                     {tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
Example 1
\chapter{Example 2}
Example 2
\section{Section example}
Section example
\subsection{Subsection example}
Subsection example

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entryformat=\normalfont,
                      pagenumberformat=\normalfont,
                      entrynumberformat={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~}},
                      linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill, 
                      numsep=1em,
                      beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,
                      dynnumwidth]
                     {tocline}{chapter}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Example 1}
Example 1
\chapter{Example 2}
Example 2
\section{Section example}
Section example
\subsection{Subsection example}
Subsection example
\chapter*{Discussion}\label{ch:discussion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:discussion}}
\chapter*{Future work}\label{ch:future-work}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:future-work}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add sections which are not chapters or sections (e.g. reference list, conclusion page etc)? Please see the update in my original post.

Comment: @MB: I just updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. One final query: is it possible for each chapter in the ToC to begin with a captial letter followed by lowercase letters (e.g. Chapter 1)? I thought of swapping `\MakeUppercase` with `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, but this led to many error messages.

Comment: `entrynumberformat={\chaptername~}` instead of `entrynumberformat={\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~}}` should result in the expected output.